# How to figure out which function of a shared library is used if linking fails due to missing -lX fails?

Tags: c, dynamic-linking, autoconf

Expanding a bit: given a project that you didn't see before and a linking failure like `/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -lperl` caused by `gcc -shared  -o PERLUAFS/ukernel.so -fPIC -Wl,-E -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt PERLUAFS/ukernel_swig_perl.o .libs/libuafs_pic.a /home/richter/openafs/lib/libcmd_pic.a /home/richter/openafs/lib/libafsutil_pic.a /home/richter/openafs/lib/libopr_pic.a -L/home/richter/openafs/lib -L/home/richter/openafs/lib -lafshcrypto -lrokenafs -lcrypt -lresolv`

How would I figure out the functions which are used for linking to be passed to `autoconf`'s `AC_CHECK_LIB` which doesn't allow omitting the function name and even if it would I'd still prefer to know exactly which functions are used.

The most trivial answer: ask the author(s) of the code which I would always do, but I'm interested in a theoretical solution as well.

Steps to resolv are imo:

- determine the implementation source file which creates the `.a` files -> Assuming you have a `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` which create `Makefile.in` and `Makefile` with thousands of lines what's the best proceedure here
- check the source and findout where functions of the library `X` used by `-lX` are used

I have no idea how to do any of those. I would also be happy with a listing of complications which can be solved infinitely faster by the original author(s) than me so that I will really no ever try to solve this task.

Comment: Search in google with error tips, then you will find a page about which library is missing.

Comment: Since I'm looking for a deterministic way, like a cooking recipe, and already mentioned contacting the developers and asking, I don't think that's a solution.